# Understanding glibc malloc trimming

Tags: linux, malloc, free, glibc

Some program that I am currently working on consumes much more memory than I think it should. So I am trying to understand how glibc malloc trimming works. I wrote the following test:

```
#include <malloc.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_CHUNKS 1000000
#define CHUNCK_SIZE 100

int main()
{
    // disable fast bins
    mallopt(M_MXFAST, 0);

    void** array  = (void**)malloc(sizeof(void*) * NUM_CHUNKS);

    // allocating memory
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_CHUNKS; i++)
    {
        array[i] = malloc(CHUNCK_SIZE);
    }

    // releasing memory ALMOST all memory
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < NUM_CHUNKS - 1 ; i++)
    {
        free(array[i]);
    }

    // when enabled memory consumption reduces
    //int ret = malloc_trim(0);
    //printf("ret=%d\n", ret);

    malloc_stats();

    sleep(100000);
}
```

Test output (without calling malloc_trim):

```
Arena 0:
system bytes     =  112054272
in use bytes     =        112
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =  120057856
in use bytes     =    8003696
max mmap regions =          1
max mmap bytes   =    8003584
```

Even though almost all memory was released, this test code consumes much more resident memory than expected:

```
[root@node0-b3]# ps aux | grep test
root     14662  1.8  0.4 129736 **118024** pts/10  S    20:19   0:00 ./test
```

Process smaps:

```
0245e000-08f3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
Size:             109428 kB
Rss:              109376 kB
Pss:              109376 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:    109376 kB
Referenced:       109376 kB
Anonymous:        109376 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac 
7f1c60720000-7f1c60ec2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:               7816 kB
Rss:                7816 kB
Pss:                7816 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      7816 kB
Referenced:         7816 kB
Anonymous:          7816 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

When I enable the call to malloc_trim the output of the test stays almost the same:

```
ret=1
Arena 0:
system bytes     =  112001024
in use bytes     =        112
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =  120004608
in use bytes     =    8003696
max mmap regions =          1
max mmap bytes   =    8003584
```

However, the RSS decreases significantly:

```
[root@node0-b3]# ps aux | grep test
root     15733  0.6  0.0 129688  **8804** pts/10   S    20:20   0:00 ./test
```

Process smaps (after malloc_trim):

```
01698000-08168000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
Size:             109376 kB
Rss:                   8 kB
Pss:                   8 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:         8 kB
Referenced:            8 kB
Anonymous:             8 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
VmFlags: rd wr mr mw me ac 
7f508122a000-7f50819cc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
Size:               7816 kB
Rss:                7816 kB
Pss:                7816 kB
Shared_Clean:          0 kB
Shared_Dirty:          0 kB
Private_Clean:         0 kB
Private_Dirty:      7816 kB
Referenced:         7816 kB
Anonymous:          7816 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
Swap:                  0 kB
KernelPageSize:        4 kB
MMUPageSize:           4 kB
Locked:                0 kB
```

After calling malloc_trim, the heap got shunked. I assume the 8MB mmap segment is still available because of the last piece of memory which wasn't released.

Why heap trimming isn't performed automatically by malloc?
Is there a way to configure malloc such that trimming will be done automatically (when it can save that much of a memory)?

I am using glibc version 2.17.

Comment: If you are using a lot of memory and need it handled in particular ways, I recommend doing it yourself using `mmap` on POSIX and `VirtualAlloc` on Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Largely for historical reasons, memory for small allocations comes from a pool managed with the [`brk`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/brk) system call.  This is a very old system call — at least as old as  [Version 6 Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix) — and the only thing it can do is *change the size* of an "arena" whose position in memory is fixed.  What that means is, the `brk` pool cannot shrink past a block that is still allocated.

Your program allocates N blocks of memory and then deallocates N-1 of them.  The one block it doesn't deallocate is the one located at the *highest* address.  That is the worst-case scenario for `brk`: the size can't be reduced at all, even though 99.99% of the pool is unused!  If you change your program so that the block it doesn't free is `array[0]` instead of `array[NUM_CHUNKS-1]`, you should see both RSS and address space shrink upon the final call to `free`.

When you explicitly call `malloc_trim`, it attempts to work around this limitation using a Linux extension, [`madvise(MADV_DONTNEED)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise), which releases the physical RAM, but not the address space (as you observed).  I don't know why this only happens upon an explicit call to `malloc_trim`.

Incidentally, the 8MB mmap segment is for your initial allocation of `array`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I saw that the `array` indeed resides on the 8MB segment, and I also saw that `array[N-1]` resides at the **end** of the heap segment. If it is in the end of it, I now don't understand how it can be trimmed (when calling `malloc_trim`).

Comment: I understand, thank you. Is there a way for me to reduce the amount of RSS memory consumed? Besides calling `malloc_trim` every now and then?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is slotting in [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/).

Comment: Changing malloc implementation is not an option for me.

Comment: Well, this is fundamentally a limitation in glibc's `malloc`, so if the control you get from `mallopt` and `malloc_trim` is not good enough, replacing the implementation is pretty much your only option.  I did mention this limitation to the glibc developers, here: https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2016-07/msg00646.html but that's probably not going to help you anytime soon, especially if you're stuck with 2.17 (when they're about to release 2.24).