# Windows vs Linux - C++ Thread Pool Memory Usage

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-management

I have been looking at the memory usage of some C++ REST API frameworks in Windows and Linux (Debian). In particular, I have looked at these two frameworks: [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/microsoft/cpprestsdk) and [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib). In both, a thread pool is created and used to service requests.

I took the thread pool implementation from [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib) and put it in a minimal working example below, to show the memory usage that I am observing on Windows and Linux.

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// TaskQueue and ThreadPool taken from https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib
class TaskQueue {
public:
    TaskQueue() = default;
    virtual ~TaskQueue() = default;

    virtual void enqueue(std::function<void()> fn) = 0;
    virtual void shutdown() = 0;

    virtual void on_idle() {};
};

class ThreadPool : public TaskQueue {
public:
    explicit ThreadPool(size_t n) : shutdown_(false) {
        while (n) {
            threads_.emplace_back(worker(*this));
            cout << "Thread number " << threads_.size() + 1 << " has ID " << threads_.back().get_id() << endl;
            n--;
        }
    }

    ThreadPool(const ThreadPool&) = delete;
    ~ThreadPool() override = default;

    void enqueue(std::function<void()> fn) override {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        jobs_.push_back(fn);
        cond_.notify_one();
    }

    void shutdown() override {
        // Stop all worker threads...
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
            shutdown_ = true;
        }

        cond_.notify_all();

        // Join...
        for (auto& t : threads_) {
            t.join();
        }
    }

private:
    struct worker {
        explicit worker(ThreadPool& pool) : pool_(pool) {}

        void operator()() {
            for (;;) {
                std::function<void()> fn;
                {
                    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(pool_.mutex_);

                    pool_.cond_.wait(
                        lock, [&] { return !pool_.jobs_.empty() || pool_.shutdown_; });

                    if (pool_.shutdown_ && pool_.jobs_.empty()) { break; }

                    fn = pool_.jobs_.front();
                    pool_.jobs_.pop_front();
                }

                assert(true == static_cast<bool>(fn));
                fn();
            }
        }

        ThreadPool& pool_;
    };
    friend struct worker;

    std::vector<std::thread> threads_;
    std::list<std::function<void()>> jobs_;

    bool shutdown_;

    std::condition_variable cond_;
    std::mutex mutex_;
};

// MWE
class ContainerWrapper {
public:
    ~ContainerWrapper() {
        cout << "Destructor: data map is of size " << data.size() << endl;
    }

    map<pair<string, string>, double> data;
};

void handle_post() {
    
    cout << "Start adding data, thread ID: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;

    ContainerWrapper cw;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5000; ++i) {
        string date = "2020-08-11";
        string id = "xxxxx_" + std::to_string(i);
        double value = 1.5;
        cw.data[make_pair(date, id)] = value;
    }

    cout << "Data map is now of size " << cw.data.size() << endl;

    unsigned pause = 3;
    cout << "Sleep for " << pause << " seconds." << endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(pause));
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    cout << "ID of main thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << endl;

    std::unique_ptr<TaskQueue> task_queue(new ThreadPool(40));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        
        cout << "Add task number: " << i + 1 << endl;
        task_queue->enqueue([]() { handle_post(); });

        // Sleep enough time for the task to finish.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
    }

    task_queue->shutdown();

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this MWE and look at the memory consumption in Windows vs Linux, I get the graph below. For Windows, I used `perfmon` to get the *Private Bytes* value. In Linux, I used `docker stats --no-stream --format "{{.MemUsage}}` to log the container's memory usage. This was in line with `res` for the process from `top` running inside the container. It appears from the graph that when a thread allocates memory for the `map` variable in Windows in the `handle_post` function, that the memory is *given back* when the function exits before the next call to the function. This was the type of behaviour that I was naively expecting. I have no experience regarding how the OS deals with memory allocated by a function that is being executed in a thread when the thread stays alive i.e. like here in a thread pool. On Linux, it looks like the memory usage keeps growing and that memory is not *given back* when the function exits. When all 40 threads have been used, and there are 10 more tasks to process, the memory usage appears to stop growing. Can somebody give a high level view of what is happening here in Linux from a memory management point of view or even some pointers about where to look for some background info on this specific topic?

**Edit 1**: I have edited the graph below to show the output value of `rss` from running `ps -p <pid> -h -o etimes,pid,rss,vsz` every second in the Linux container where `<pid>` is the id of the process being tested. It is in reasonable agreement with the output of `docker stats --no-stream --format "{{.MemUsage}}`.

[image: win_v_lin_50_seq_tasks_40_threads_rss]

**Edit 2**: Based on a comment below regarding STL allocators, I removed the map from MWE by replacing the `handle_post` function with the following and adding the includes `#include <cstdlib>` and `#include <cstring>`. Now, the `handle_post` function just allocates and sets memory for 500K `int`s which is approximately 2MiB.

```cpp
void handle_post() {
    
    size_t chunk = 500000 * sizeof(int);
    if (int* p = (int*)malloc(chunk)) {

        memset(p, 1, chunk);
        cout << "Allocated and used " << chunk << " bytes, thread ID: " << this_thread::get_id() << endl;
        cout << "Memory address: " << p << endl;

        unsigned pause = 3;
        cout << "Sleep for " << pause << " seconds." << endl;
        this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(pause));

        free(p);
    }
}
```

I get the same behaviour here. I reduced the number of threads to 8 and the number of tasks to 10 in the example. The graph below shows the results.

**Edit 3**: I have added the results from running on a Linux CentOS machine. It broadly agrees with the results from the Debian docker image result.

[image: 8_threads_10_seq_tasks_e3]

**Edit 4**: Based on another comment below, I ran the example under `valgrind`'s `massif` tool. The `massif` command line parameters are in the images below. I ran it with `--pages-as-heap=yes`, second image below, and without this flag, first image below. The first image would suggest that ~2MiB memory is allocated to the (shared) heap as the `handle_post` function is executed on a thread and then freed as the function exits. This is what I would expect and what I observe on Windows. I am not sure how to interpret the graph with `--pages-as-heap=yes` yet, i.e. the second image.

I can't reconcile the output of `massif` in the first image with the value of `rss` from the `ps` command shown in the graphs above. If I run the Docker image and limit the container memory to 12MB using `docker run --rm -it --privileged --memory="12m" --memory-swap="12m" --name=mwe_test cpp_testing:1.0`, the container runs out of memory on the 7th allocation and is killed by the OS. I get `Killed` in the output and when I look at `dmesg`, I see `Killed process 25709 (cpp_testing) total-vm:529960kB, anon-rss:10268kB, file-rss:2904kB, shmem-rss:0kB`. This would suggest that the `rss` value from `ps` is accurately reflecting the (heap) memory *actually* being used by the process whereas the `massif` tool is calculating what it *should* be based on `malloc`/`new` and `free`/`delete` calls. This is just my basic assumption from this test. My question would still stand i.e. why is, or does it appear that, the heap memory is not being freed or deallocated when the `handle_post` function exits?

[image: massif_output]

**Edit 5**: I have added below a graph of the memory usage as you increase the number of threads in the thread pool from 1 to 4. The pattern continues as you increase the number of threads up to 10 so I have not included 5 to 10. Note that I have added a 5 sec pause at the start of `main` which is the initial flat line in the graph for the first ~5secs. It appears that, regardless of thread count, there is a release of memory after the first task is processed but that memory is not released (kept for reuse?) after task 2 through 10. It may suggest that some memory allocation parameter is tuned during task 1 execution (just thinking out loud!)?

[image: increase_num_threads]

**Edit 6**: Based on the suggestion from the detailed answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497719/1771882), I set the environment variable `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` to 1 and 2 before running the example. This gives the output in the following graph. This is as expected based on the explanation of the effect of this variable given in the answer.

[image: effect_of_malloc_arena_max]

Comment: One OS difference I think of first is Windows has a default stack size of 1 MB. linux its larger. 8 to 10MB I believe.

Comment: @drescherjm thanks. If I increase the number of elements added to the map in `handle_post` from 5K to 50K, the Linux line grows linearly to ~140 MB before flat lining whereas the Windows line remains at ~13 MB with drops after each task is processed. This is what confuses me. Even though the destructor of the struct wrapping the map is called when the function exits, the memory allocated appears to remain in play on Linux. Again, I have very little experience here so may just have a very basic misunderstanding.

Comment: You have piqued my curiosity: I looked up what `MemUsage` means to `docker stats` and all I could find was this: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stats/ Not helpful. There are literally _dozens_ of different ways to measure how much "memory" is being "used" by a process, and depending on what is reported by the Windows and Linux versions of docker as "memory usage," you may be comparing apples to architecture.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for having a look. The `docker stats` output agreed with the output from running `top` inside the container and looking at the `res` column. The `top` value of `res` was a little bit lower because it was only the process itself that was being monitored. I can edit the question and update the graph with this result. I have access to a Linux server running CentOS so I can add the result from there also. May be useful to update the question with these stats.

Comment: Assuming no memory leak (check valgrind), I've seen this happen with the implementation-provided STL container allocators. It may allocate some space up and not give it back unless needed. For kicks and giggles, try comparing debug/release builds as well. I would suspect STL, docker, and malloc before the OS, although admittedly I don't know whether or not there are cases where Linux would be so nonchalant about reclaiming a process' freed memory.

Comment: @HumphreyWinnebago Thanks for the feedback/suggestions. I ran a debug build of the example and I saw the same behaviour. I also ran the debug build under `valgrind` and it reported no issues. I made an edit to the question to remove the `map` and use only `malloc`, `memset` and `free` in the `handle_post` method. I still see the same behaviour, shown in the second graph. I will keep digging!

Comment: Valgrind should have options to show the actual memory usage (computed from allocs and frees). The Linux kernel may keep the pages of a process reserved but not committed and eventually reclaim them *only when actually needed*. The fact that the memory usage tops at a maximum may be an indicator of this behavior. Try doing a memory stress of the system while the process is still active and see if Linux reduces its memory usage.

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks for the feedback/suggestions. I have updated the question with the output of `valgrind`'s `massif` tool. The result with `--pages-as-heap=no` is confusing me. It shows the behaviour that I would expect yet when I stress the container after limiting its memory the OS kills the process. If I was judging by the `massif` output, I would expect the container memory usage to stay around ~2MB. There is probably just a gap in my understanding between what `rss` from `ps` is showing me versus the amount of memory that is allocated by the process on the heap.

Comment: Then there must be something else going on :/ I'm not sure the containerization is not at fault here. Maybe *cgroups* (the actual component that imposes constraints on the containers) doesn't take into account reclaimable memory

Comment: @MargaretBloom Thanks again, this is very helpful. I didn't fully understand your first comment initially. I did a bit of reading and I came across this article: https://lemire.me/blog/2020/03/03/calling-free-or-delete/. I think that it is along the same lines as what you were suggesting. When I call `free` in `handle_post`, the memory is not necessarily returned to the OS, hence the difference between `massif` and `rss`. Do you feel that if the memory sizes were increased and this was run on a Linux machine that the OS would reclaim the `free`'d space if it started running out of memory?

Comment: I'd expect so. But that's just my mental model, I never really tried to prove or disprove it :)

Comment: @MargaretBloom for completeness, I ran a non-containerised version of the MWE on a Linux server with 64GB RAM. I used 5 million elements in the map in `handle_post` which lead to a memory usage of ~5-10GB while processing each task. I added a 2 min sleep in `main` so that each task was processed in series. This triggered the OOM manager to kill the example. So, I don't think that the containerisation is at fault here. I am still not sure what is though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many modern allocators, including the one in glibc 2.17 that you are using, use multiple *arenas* (a structure which tracks free memory regions) in order to avoid contention between threads which want to allocate at the same time.

Memory freed back to one arena isn't available to be allocated by another arena (unless some type of cross-arena transfer is triggered).

By default, glibc will allocate new arenas every time a new thread makes an allocation, until a predefined limit is hit (which defaults to 8 * number of CPUs) as you can see by [examining the code](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/release/2.17/master/malloc/arena.c#L831).

One consequence of this is that memory allocated then freed on a thread may not be available to other threads since they are using separate areas, even if that thread isn't doing any useful work.

You can try setting the [glibc malloc tunable](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Tunables.html) `glibc.malloc.arena_max` to `1` in order to force all threads to the same arena and see if it changes the behavior you were observing.

Note that this has everything to do with the userspace allocator (in libc) and nothing to do with the OS allocation of memory: the OS is never informed that the memory has been freed. *Even if* you force a single arena, it doesn't mean that the userspace allocator will decide to inform the OS: it may simply keep the memory around to satisfy a future request (there are tunables to adjust this behavior also).

However, in your test using a single arena should be enough to prevent the constantly increasing memory footprint since the memory is freed before the next thread starts, and so we expect it to be reused by the next task, which starts on a different thread.

Finally, it is worth pointing out that what happens is highly dependent on exactly how threads are notified by the condition variable: presumably Linux uses a FIFO behavior, where the most recently queued (waiting) thread will be the last to be notified. This causes you to cycle through all the threads as you add tasks, causing many arenas to be created. A more efficient pattern (for a variety of reasons) is a LIFO policy: use the most recently enqueued thread for the next job. This would cause the same thread to be repeatedly reused in your test and "solve" the problem.

Final note: many allocators, but not the on in the older version of glibc that you are using, also implement a *per-thread cache* which allows the allocation fast path to proceed without *any* atomic operations. This can produce a similar effect to the use of multiple arenas, and which keeps scaling with the number of threads.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info, I didn't know about this. It doesn't appear to be the issue with my example though. I am using GNU libc version 2.17 and the per thread cache was not introduced until version 2.26. I tried it just in case, i.e. `GLIBC_TUNABLES=glibc.malloc.tcache_count=0`, `export GLIBC_TUNABLES` and then run the test, and the result is the same i.e. memory grows to ~16MiB. One thing I notice high level from the `rss` graph is that the memory drops after the 1st task is completed, grows for the next 8 tasks and appears to reuse memory on the 10th task.

Comment: @Francis - does the behavior look the same if you do the same patterns of allocations, but on a single thread? Could you add a threadid output to your program to check which threads are being selected by the thread pool (i.e., if my FIFO assumption is correct)? Even without a thread-cache, many allocators will try to implement a "per CPU" cache or something like that, which might use thread ID as an approximation, so it's possible malloc is still allocating stuff in different arenas.

Comment: I added an edit, Edit 5 piece at the end, to the original question showing the memory usage as you increase from one thread to four in the thread pool. As I see it, the behaviour is pretty much the same regardless of thread count i.e. memory released after first task but not on subsequent tasks. If the `malloc`'s are made large enough, memory is released on every task. However, using a `map` instead of `malloc` and adding to it in `handle_post`, the memory usage can be made arbitrarily large and it is not released. I observed the FIFO behaviour on almost all runs, but not always.

Comment: @Francis - how many logical cores do you have? Anyway, I updated my answer since it seems that even older versions of glibc still used "mostly" per thread arenas, up to a max count of 8 per core, which would cause the same effect as per-thread caches. There is a tunable you can use to adjust this too and see if it's your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this detailed answer. I added an edit, Edit 6, to the question showing the effect of setting `MALLOC_ARENA_MAX` to 1 and 2 versus not setting it and allowing it to default. The graph is as expected based on reading your answer. The number of logical cores on my test server was 32 (=> max arena = 256) and the number on my local windows machine (running the example in a Docker container) was 8 (=> max arena = 64). Thanks again.

Comment: @Francis - glad it worked, second time the charm! I don't think the arenas will actually cause an indefinite amount of memory to be accumulated per thread, there is probably some point at which the memory will be released or repurposed, but your test does not reach this threshold. If you do a web search for the tunable, you'll find a few places complaining about high memory use and this tunable comes up.

Comment: [tcmalloc](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc) is a nice example of an allocator whose memory consumption doesn't scale with nthreads. It uses [restartable sequences](https://github.com/compudj/librseq) and per core arenas. Fallback if `rseq` is not supported (windows for example) may be per thread.