# Why is memory not returned to the system after all objects are deleted and cleared?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <list>
#include <thread>

struct a {
  char data[1024];
};

struct b {
  char data[1024];
};

struct c {
  char data[1024];
};

struct d {
  char data[1024];
};

int main() {
  std::list<a *> a_list;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    a_list.push_back(new a);
  }

  std::list<b *> b_list;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    b_list.push_back(new b);
  }

  std::list<c *> c_list;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    c_list.push_back(new c);
  }

  std::list<d *> d_list;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    d_list.push_back(new d);
  }

  printf("---\n"); // line A
  while (a_list.size() > 0) {
    a *item = a_list.front();
    a_list.pop_front();
    delete item;
  }

  printf("---\n");
  while (b_list.size() > 0) {
    b *item = b_list.front();
    b_list.pop_front();
    delete item;
  }

  printf("---\n");
  while (c_list.size() > 0) {
    c *item = c_list.front();
    c_list.pop_front();
    delete item;
  }

  printf("---\n");
  while (d_list.size() > 0) {
    d *item = d_list.front();
    d_list.pop_front();
    delete item;
  }

  printf("end\n"); // inline B

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::hours(1));
}
```

At line A, the process memory usage is 26%. At line B, the process memory usage is 26%!

Why does this happen?

More cases:

1. When I remove `b`, `c`, and `d` and just leave `a`, the results are the same.
   If I make the `a` array's length to be `130000`, the results are the same, but when I grow it to be 140000, the results were different: memory was actually freed.
2. After free lines, I added more code to allocate more memory for more items using `new`, then the memory usage goes up, but the number of bytes allocated was smaller than first time.

Comment: A process isn't required to return freed memory back to the OS. It can hold on to it for later to make future allocations faster.

Comment: Phrased another way, your memory _is_ returned to the system, and you are seeing that _the system_ is deciding to continue associating it with your process.

Comment: [Why don't memory allocators actively return freed memory to the OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538993/why-dont-memory-allocators-actively-return-freed-memory-to-the-os)

Comment: Phrased another way, the memory of those objects is returned to your process's heap manager, and your heap manager is deciding whether or not to return the memory block to the operating system.  (And probably won't release the memory to the OS until the OS has memory pressure and requests processes to relinquish excess memory blocks, if they have any.)

Comment: Note, too, that the OS assigns entire memory *pages* to processes. As long as any other data yet resides there memory won't be returned either, and processes *do* contain further data apart from what you allocated (compiled code, stack, global variables, ...).

Answer (score 0):

note: this is not my answer, I am quoting this from a comment by
MX. Andrieux
"a process isn't required to return freed memory back to the OS, it can hold on to it for later to future allocations faster."

I'm certain that the program will return said memory upon closing the program.
although any files created by the program will remain in disk memory after closing the program.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: but if that ture,  after billion objects allocated, other process even itself cannot reuse the momery, the process just hold the memory。

Comment: when i create other process, allocate more memory, the old process just killed by system due to the memory